# How to get the first row details using rowcount?

Tags: sql, rowcount

I have a temp variable called @rows having nearly 10000 records in a stored procedure like this

```
Create Procedure input
as
begin
declare @input_data table(......)
insert into (.....) from ....
@rows= select @@rowcount
while(@rows > o)
begin
--- I need to process each row like
select ... where @row=1 --like this repeatedly upto @rows = 10000
end
```

How should I achieve this.Please help me
Thanks in advance

Comment: Rarely is a loop/cursor the best approach in SQL operations. It is a set based language, and often there is a set based solution that just hasn't been found yet. Perhaps consider asking a new question for assistance in finding the set based solution, rather than seeking assistance on fixing your procedural solution. It will almost certainly pay dividends in terms of performance (I can't offer any advice since I don't know what you are doing to each row).

Answer (score 0):

You can directly update the table based on some conditiuons and using CASE statement insted of using while loop.

Comment: How could I use case statement for that ? Please suggest me with some examples

Comment: if you show me what to update and table structures then i can help

Answer (score 0):

You may achieve your goal using a CURSOR

```
DECLARE @ID AS INT

DECLARE TestCursor CURSOR
FOR (SELECT ID FROM Test)

OPEN TestCursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM TestCursor INTO @ID

    WHILE @@Fetch_Status = 0
    BEGIN
        --Your Code Here
        PRINT  @ID --Print For Testing
        FETCH NEXT FROM TestCursor INTO @ID
    END

CLOSE TestCursor
DEALLOCATE TestCursor
```

Remember : using cursors will lead to a performance loss
Instead use CASE statements in queries for conditional selections/updates, as described in another answer

Comment: How could I use case statement for that ? Please suggest me with some examples.

Comment: Do you really need to update/select multiple records (all records) or a single record? Your goal is not 100% clear! Please explain little more